# Fitting a multi-variable function with errors

Tags: python

How can I fit a multi-variable function, taking into account the uncertainties of the individual variables? In other words, if e.g.

```
func = lambda p, x, y: (p[0] * x ** p[1]) + (p[2] * y ** p[3])
```

and

```
errfunc = lambda p, x, y, z, xerr, yerr : (z - func(p, x, y))/err
```

what would "`err`" be?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the mathematics of that (then we might need more context to understand your question) or is this a programming problem (then you might need to rephrase it to make clearer what you want and what is not working, yet)?

Comment: Which error function do you need: the PDF of a multivariate function, or the loss function for regression?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm asking about the mathematics of how to fit a model to z(x,y) function, taking into account the (x,y) errors. 

I tried simply adding another dimension to the 1-d least squares y(x) fitting, i.e. instead of having

"(y - func(p, x))/xerr"

in errfunc, I do

"(z - func(p, x, y))/sqrt(xerr^2 + yerr^2)"

but that didn't look right.